# Redirect from one route to another in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have following routes in nodejs

here is `users.js` route

```
router.post('/users/login', function(request, response) {
    // let user login here and do all of the logic.

    // Once done then redirect user to dashboard in dashboard.js file
    response.redirect('/dashboard');
});
```

here is dashboard.js route

```
 router.get('/dashboard', function(request, response) {
     response.render('plans');
 });
```

Now when I login as a user when it tries to redirect me it says following.

```
cannot get Cannot GET /users/dashboard
```

I want users' to redirect to `/dashboard/dashboard` instead.

How can I redirect users from one route to another in Express?

Comment: You may need to be more explicit with your route redirect -- it seems to remain inside the directory (maybe not the right work since it's a route) `/users`. Try `response.redirect('/dashboard/dashboard');` if that doesn't work, maybe relative `..` will help?

Comment: His redirect should work tho, accordingly too the [docs](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#res.redirect) '/path' should be relative to root and without leading slash it should be relative to the current path. @2619 could you check your response redirect headers in the browser?

Answer (score 39):

I had the same doubt as you had, I came here to look for the answer but found none so I had to do some digging in the docs myself for the solution, and I found one.

Using **res.redirect('/dashboard')** is taking to the path which is relative to the current route i.e users/dashboard, if you have a separate route for dashboard then you'll have to use it this way:
**res.redirect('../dashboard/dashboard')**

Just for reference here is my project structure:

```
routes/
> index.js
> user_home.js
> users.js
```

Here are the contents of `user_home.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("Hello User, welcome to user_home page");
});

router.get('/dashboard', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("Hello User, this your personal dashboard");
});

module.exports = router;
```

and here is the code from the route from where i am redirecting :

```
else {
      console.log("Input validated!");
      res.redirect('../user_home/dashboard');  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't do `response.redirect('/dashboard');` with a `/` in it, as this will add `/dashboard` to the current url. Do this instead: `response.redirect('dashboard');`.

Answer (score 2):

in my case I've created a redirect in case I don't have a req.query parameter. So after the redirect I added a return.

```
       if(req.query.tk==null)
    {
        res.redirect('landing-page');
        return;
    }....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
res.redirect('auth/login');
```

I had this in one of my route named 'contributions' and when it is redirected, it is rendered as 'contributions/auth/login' which is wrong.

The main thing i needed was 'localhost://port/auth/login.

i changed my ejs anchor tag to '/auth/login' which will take url from the root, It previously was 'auth/login' which took the url as current url + provided url, i.e., 'contributions/auth/login' in my case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i don't find it relevant.

Answer (score -1):

Yup I am just 5 years late anyway, you are redirecting from a 'get' request to a 'post' request. That is why you are getting this error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).