# How do I delegate a request to a particular route in nodejs express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
const API_VERSION = {
    "authenticate"     : "v1",
    "users'"           : "v1",
    "requests"         : "v2",
}
```

I have following routes:

```
app.use('/api/v1/authenticate', authenticate);
app.use('/api/v1/users', users);
app.use('/api/v1/requests', requestService);
app.use('/api/v2/requests', requestService_v2);
```

If a request comes for say `api/v1/authenticate`, then it should be re-routed to `api/v2/authenticate`.

I tried

```
app.use('/api/v2/*', (req, res, next) => {
    const originalUrl = req.originalUrl;
    const endPoint = originalUrl.match(/(?<=\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/)[^\/]+(?=\/)/g)[0].toLowerCase();
    req.baseUrl = req.originalUrl.replace("v2", API_VERSIONS[endPoint]);
    next('route');
});
```

But this does not work.

Comment: You should be able to use `res.redirect(....);` See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44445540/3284355 it might help you with the url needed.

Comment: @Molda, thank you, it worked with res.redirect(307, url);

Comment: I believe that will redirect the client so there will be another request from the client but there's internal redirect possible. Try without the `307`.

Comment: @Molda without 307, the http method changes from POST to GET

Answer (score 0):

I use app all and pipe the request after modifying the url. You can also reroute it to a diff. server e.g.

```
  API_V1 = '/api/v1'
  app.all('/api/v2/*', (req, res)->
    url = API_V1 + req.url
    req.pipe(request[req.method.toLowerCase()](url, (error)->
      res.json({err: error}) if error?
    )).pipe(res).on
  )
```

I haven't tried your code but maybe just call next()

Comment: Thank you for the response, 
but I did not understand how that pipe thing works and from where that request object came.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following

```
app.use('/api/v2/*', (req, res, next) => {
    const originalUrl = req.originalUrl;
    const endPoint = originalUrl.match(/(?<=\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/)[^\/]+(?=\/)/g)[0].toLowerCase();
    const url = req.originalUrl.replace("v2", API_VERSIONS[endPoint]);
    res.redirect(307, url);
});
```

It works, but I'm eager to know if there's any other way to do it.