# NodeJS redirect to internal localhost server

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodejs so apologies if this is a bad question.

I am using NodeJS + Auth0 to authenticate a shiny webapp. I have most of it working now including the call back but am stuck on the last step.

Assuming it authenticates, I want to proxy pass directly to 127.0.0.1:3838/myapp.

In other words, if the loopback address **were** public I could do:

```
res.redirect('http://127.0.0.1:3838/myapp/');
```

However, as it's not public that is no longer an option. Any advice?

Comment: do you have the IP of the internal server that you could use?

Comment: @khuynh: Not sure I follow your comment? The internal rshiny server listens only on the loopback address and port 3838.

Comment: Use a reverse proxy application to talk to your server. Try something like frp or nginx. Note in order to use either of these, you will need a server with a public IP address. I personally like FRP because I use it to expose many locally hosted applications and have even used it in the past to expose RDP to the internet.

Comment: @smac89: I already have this node app running behind nginx. Essentially, you go to mydomain.com/myapp -> Nginx redirects it to a node server that listens on port 3000. That server is used to login. Once logged in, I want it redirected to 127.0.0.1:3838/myapp

Comment: So is the node server running on the same host as the shinny app? If so, why can't you do `res.redirect('http://127.0.0.1:3838/myapp/');` from the node server? Also what is the logic used by either nginx or your app to decide when to redirect to the node server running on port `3000`?

Comment: @smac89: Because if I do res.redirect to that address, it literally points the browser to 127.0.0.1. Since the user is somewhere else, and 127.0.0.1 is not accessible from that machine it's a page not found. Regarding your question, my nginx listsens to https://mydoimain.com/myapp1. It then redirects that to Node on port 3000.  Someone can go to that app directly using the port information as its just a login page. That's why I think the redirect needs to be a proxy pass.

Answer (score 0):

```js
res.redirect('/myapp'):
```

Should redirect you to the `/myapp` route assuming that you are running the NodeJS app locally on `127.0.0.1:3838`

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44445540/16471349

Comment: That doesn't work. If i redirect to /myapp, that is what is initially captured by nginx as from the outside world it's listening to myserver.com/myapp. It needs to redirect specifically to 127.0.0.1:3838/myapp which is only available internally.