# PassportJS `logout()` request stuck pending

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

When calling the passport `logout()` function to clear cookie session, http request gets stuck pending:

I set the routes in `auth.routes.ts`:

```js
router.get('/login', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.render("google-login");
});

router.post('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
    req.logout(function(err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        res.redirect('/auth/login');
    });
});
```

and use the routes in `app.ts`:

```js
app.use(cookieSession({
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 24h * 60m * 60s * 1000ms in a second 
    keys: [process.env.SESSION_KEY] // encrypt/decrypt using this key
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());''

app.use('/auth', auth_routes);
```

Users are being properly serialized/deserialized in `passport-setup.ts`:

```js
passport.serializeUser((user: any, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
});
    
passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    logger.info("deserialize id: " + id);
    GoogleUserModel.findById(id).then((user) => {
        done(null, user);
    });
})
```

Basic profile page to display user data `profile.ejs`:

```html
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <form action="/auth/logout" method="POST">
                <button type="submit">Logout</button>
            </form>
            <li><a href="/auth/login">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <header>
        <h2> Welcome <%= google_user.name %>! </h2>
        <h4> Info </h4>
        <p> Email: <%= google_user.email %> </p>
        <p> Google ID: <%= google_user.google_id %> </p>
        <p> Database ID: <%= google_user.id %> </p>
    </header>
</body>
```

The cookie is still there as shown through the dev console:

[image: logout request]
[image: preceding redirect request after login]
When the `logout` button is pressed the route is hit but gets stuck in the `req.logout()` function. The correct user is being accessed before that as well. I'm just lost on why the request is getting stuck pending and not redirecting

Comment: Is the callback being called?

Comment: @kelsny the error callback is not. 
Edit: after doing some more logging the logout() function is invoked, but the pending begins once the callback is hit.

Comment: I think you're redirecting to the wrong path so the server just ignores the request. Can you try variations like `"/login"` and `"auth/login"`? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42034898/redirect-from-one-route-to-another-in-express

Comment: @kelsny I saw that thread too, I tried a few variations and still getting the same thing. I'm setting these routes to use`/auth` in my main app file. I should note, I just double clicked on the `logout` request and instead I got a `Cannot GET /auth/logout` error, which is interesting since it's a POST request